# Control size of Facebook auth dialog

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) for my WP7 app. The [authentication dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) that prompts the user to grant permission to the app is displayed full screen on the app (about 480px I guess), but the allow/don't allow button are hidden at the bottom of the frame, which needs to scroll. There is a large part of the screen that is white though, so I think Facebook is serving a dialog for a larger screen.

**How can I specify the size of the screen when authenticating over Facebook oauth ?**

Comment: I think while preparing login url,  use display=touch as query string.

Comment: @Mahantesh Right now there is a bug with the Facebook login screen on the WP7 browser when using the touch display and it doesn't work. Using the touch login page would be my suggestion too though. :(

Comment: @Thomas I also developing app for wp7, Microsoft suggested to avoid the third-party facebook and twitter logins, use the ShareLinkTask and ShareStatusStask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Facebook. I would suggest opening a bug with Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

The one thing you might do to work around the issue is to inject either javascript or css into the page using the browser control. Your javascript/css could fix this issues and resize the page. I have done that before on an old WPF app and it worked well.

Unfortunately, the Facebook support for Windows Phone is very poor and there are several major issues of this type.